# Echo.private and /broadcasting/auth 405 error

Tags: vue.js, laravel-echo

In a Vuejs/Larvel forum, I'm seeing the following error when a question and its replies are displayed:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

If I remove an Echo.private method from the component that lists the comments, the error disappears.  However, I can't see how the Echo... method is incorrect and don't know where else to look.

The relevant (I hope) code extracts are:

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'myKey',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    auth:{
        headers:{
            Authorization: JWTtoken
        }
    }
});
```

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});


Broadcast::channel('likeChannel', function () {
  return true;
});
```

replies.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p v-if="comments>0"><em>{{$t('Comments')}}</em></p>
        <reply
            v-for="(r,index) in content"
            :key="r.id"
            :index=index
            v-if="question.replies"
            :data="r"
        ></reply>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Reply from './Reply';
    import { eventBus } from '../../app';
  export default {
    name: "Replies",
    props: ['question'],
    components: {Reply},
    data(){
      return {
        content:this.question.replies,
        comments:this.question.replies.length,
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.listen();
    },
    methods: {
      listen(){
        console.log('userID='+this.UserID)

        Echo.private('App.User.' + this.UserID)
          .notification((notification) => {
            console.log('Replies 36; Notification type: '+ notification.type);
            this.content.unshift(notification.reply)
          });

        eventBus.$on('replyCreated',(reply)=>{
          this.content.unshift(reply) //unshift adds item to top of array
        });
        eventBus.$on('deleteReply',(index) => {
          axios.delete(`api/question/${this.question.slug}/reply/${this.content[index].id}`)
            .then(res => {
              this.content.splice(index,1);
            }
          )
        });
      },
    },
    computed: {
      UserID: function () {
        var tk = localStorage.getItem('token');
        var payload = tk.split('.')[1];
        var pl = JSON.parse(atob(payload));
        return pl.sub;
      },
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Commenting out all the Echo.private material removes the error; commenting out just the .notification part doesn't have the same effect suggesting it is not the contents of 'notification'.

Obviously I've revealed myself to be new and lost in space here; perhaps what I'm seeing is the consequence of a problem elsewhere - but I'm at a loss where to look elsewhere.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Show us your `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider` file. To elaborate - run `php artisan route:list | grep broadcasting`, do you have that route? If not, it's missing from the file I mentioned. If you have that file and that route, then you didn't uncomment `App\Providers\BroadcasterviceProvider::class` from your `config/app.php` file.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't uncommented that line in app.php.  Rewards!